# Tutorial demo_app won't work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to run the chapter two demo_app from the Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial book on Heroku and it is not working. gws-demp-app.heroku.com gives the default Rails page, but gws-demo-app.heroku.com/users gives a web page that says "We're sorry, but something went wrong." On my desktop it works fine. I'm using the tools from RailsInstaller.org.

I had problems with `heroku rake db:migrate` at the end of the chapter not finding the activerecord-postgresql-adapter so I did `install gem pg`, `bundle install`, and updated the Gemfile and repositories. Everything is on github at https://github.com/gwshaw/demo_app.

What looks like the same problem appears at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619551/heroku-rake-dbmigrate-success-but-not-showing-in-app
I tried `heroku restart` recommended there, but that causes: Restarting processes... C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:6
44:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (SocketError)

I tried what is claimed to work, precompiling assets with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, but that generates an error: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rake as
sets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in C:/Sites/rails_projects/demo_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)

I'm new to ruby and rails so I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Solved below.

Comment: Does your Rails app run locally? (You're going to develop locally, so get used to running the app locally.)

Comment: Have you tried running `heroku logs` to check the log file on Heroku?

Comment: No, I'm learning :-). Running them to failure I get these: 2011-10-21T16:24:30+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2011-10-21T16:24:30+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 24.4.2.21 - - [21/Oct/2011:09:24:30 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1864 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT
 6.0; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" gws-demo-app.heroku.com
2011-10-21T16:24:30+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss2011-10-21T16:24:30+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gws-demo-app.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=25ms status=404 bytes=728
...continued

Comment: 2011-10-21T16:24:30+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 24.4.2.21 - - [21/Oct/2011:09:24:30 -0700] "GET /assets/rails.png HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "http://gws-demo-app.heroku.com/" "
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" gws-demo-app.heroku.com
2011-10-21T16:24:36+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users] miss
2011-10-21T16:24:36+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gws-demo-app.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=126ms status=500 bytes=728
one last line...

Comment: 2011-10-21T16:24:36+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 24.4.2.21 - - [21/Oct/2011:09:24:36 -0700] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Window
s NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" gws-demo-app.heroku.com    I don't know how to read these, but I don't see "error" anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` was the key and is solved here [RoR Precompiling Assets fail while rake assets:precompile - on basically empty application.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7877180/1007211)

Oddly, Heroku wouldn't automatically precompile the assets on a `git push heroku` and thus would not find them. I don't think this little demo_app even uses assets, so that may be why it didn't precompile, but it still could not find `applicaiton.css` and failed. Once I set `config.log_level = :debug` in production.rb, I could see the problem in the logs. With the precompile working due to the above fix, everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

Yes , this worked for me too after installing the pg gem, I ran the following:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -am "add a note reflecting changes made"
git push
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku rake db:migrate
heroku db:push
```

after invoking these commands, I was able to successfully open the demo_app on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post — I'm new to Rails, but reading your post helped me with a very similar issue.
Here's what worked for me:

**Install pg gem to use postgreSQL on Heroku:** ([related article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664364/how-to-handle-ruby-on-rails-error-please-install-the-postgresql-adapter-gem))

```
sudo gem install pg
```

**Install taps gem to allow push of your local database to Heroku:** ([related article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps))

```
gem install taps
```

**then the following sequence…**

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -am "add a note reflecting changes made"
git push
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku rake db:migrate
heroku db:push
```

If you're still having trouble, these articles are helpful too:
[Stack Overflow - Heroku command: Heroku Rake db:migrate fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896944/heroku-command-heroku-rake-dbmigrate-fails)
[Heroku - Getting Started with Rails 3.0 on Heroku/Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)

Comment: Thanks @zed_0xff for the highlighting the syntax in the post.
After reviewing, it looks like I had modified my Gemfile too:
`gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4', :group => :development`

Comment: Thanks, but no success. I still get the same error when running the precompile locally. When I do a `git push heroku` it does a precompile and appears to complete with no errors.

Note that I've finished the tutorial and have the same issue with the completed sample_app, `gws-sample-app.heroku.com`