# RoR Precompiling Assets fail while rake assets:precompile - on basically empty application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, precompiled

Running:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace

** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in C:/Sites/MyApp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
```

Here is the entire content of `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

nothing else there.

I tried to remove the three  `//= require` lines from `application.js`, the precompilation then runs with no problems.

Comment: Which `application.js` file have you shown us the source of? Where is it located?

Comment: C:/Sites/MyApp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js the auto-generated one. I removed the three //require lines and it pre-compiled no problem, I have to assume that the jquery gems has a hiccup . I will eventually need jquery so it will be great to get this fixed. thx

Comment: Do you have jquery-rails in your Gemfile and you did bundle install?

Comment: sure. here it is:  group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like it might be a problem with uglifier and Windows Script Host:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2847

Make sure you're using the last version of uglifier (1.0.4). If you're still having problems, I'd suggest trying a different compiler (e.g. Closure compiler)

In `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'closure-compiler'
```

In `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :closure
```

alternatively disable JS compression altogether:

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, it worked! to help others:  I grabbed uglifier 1.0.4 and tried; no luck. Grabbed closure-compiler 1.1.4 , added the gem and the config changes and tried: worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank you. If the answer was helpful, please free to upvote and/or accept :)

Comment: Hi Alex, that was the first thing I tired to do, it tells me "vote up requires 15 reputation. I'm new here with a total of 1 reputation... so sorry, please don't stop helping me just because I can't say thank you properly!

Answer (score 1):

I got same sort of error

```
...>rake assets:precompile
C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe C:/Ruby192/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
...
rake aborted!
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in C:/Users/straffordw/railsApps/chorus-spp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:68:in `extract_result'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.0.1/lib/uglifier.rb:167:in `really_compile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.0.1/lib/uglifier.rb:95:in `compile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor='
...
```

and did

```
bundle update
```

which brought in

```
uglifier (2.1.1)
```

(amongst other things), then:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and that resolved my problem. Windows, Rails 3.2.11.