# Ruby on Rails: segmentation fault when running 'rake assets:precompile'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, segmentation-fault, execjs

Since two days, I am not able to compile the javascript assets in my ruby on rails project anymore. If I do not run the precompile command, the same fault occurs when ruby is compiling the assets at runtime. The 'rake assets:precompile' command aborts because of a segmentation fault:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby /home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
sh: regel 1: 15071 Segmentatiefout         node /tmp/execjs20120417-15062-69pd5q.js 2>&1
rake aborted!
["ok","(function() {\n\n\n\n}).call(this);\n"]
  (in /home/Roseboom/gitControlled/ror/livescore/app/assets/javascripts/clubs.js.coffee)
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:150:in `exec_runtime'
 [.... Remaining stacktrace below this post for the sake of readability ]
```

Here, 'Segmentatiefout' is Dutch for 'Segmentation fault'.
At first, I thought I messed something up with my project, and I started reverting changes to isolate the 'bad' change. When this did not help, I tried the 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' in a project that I did not tough for weeks, which got me the same segmentation fault.

Now I tried to locate this "execjs20120417-15062-69pd5q.js" file to just remove it. Even with the help of the unix 'find' command, I could not find that. Maybe this temp file is cleaned even when aborted.

Next thing I tried was to reinstall rake, which did not help me. Although the same fault occured when just running 'rake assets:precompile', I tried reinstalling bundler as well. This did not work out as well.

Next thing was a bit rigorously, I reinstalled ruby and rails on my system. Unfortunately, no change at all. Rails version was 3.2.2, and after this reinstalling it is 3.2.3.

Last thing I tried was to uninstall the gem execjs, and reinstall it, but no help from this as well.

Changing the RAILS_ENV to development does not change anything as well.

When I clear my app/assets/javascripts folder, I can precompile, and I can run my application (like described in [Rails assets precompile mysterious error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839608/rails-assets-precompile-mysterious-error)). I expect ruby to use the assets that were compiled succesfully before. However, this means I can never change the contents of app/assets/javascripts, which is undesirable. If I remove all the .js.coffee files that are there, the segmentation fault occurs on the .js  file that is left.

The file clubs.js.coffee is autogenerated and never changed by me. It was generated a few weeks ago and never got me problems before 2 days ago. If I remove it, the same fault occurs with just another .coffe or .js file. clubs.js.coffee contains:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
```

I am really out of ideas on this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Full stacktrace:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby /home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake assets:precompile:
all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
sh: regel 1: 15936 Segmentatiefout         node /tmp/execjs20120417-15927-1ka3s2r.js 2>&1
rake aborted!
["ok","(function() {\n\n\n\n}).call(this);\n"]
  (in /home/Roseboom/gitControlled/ror/livescore/app/assets/javascripts/clubs.js.coffee)
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:150:in `exec_runtime'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `block in exec'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:40:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:26:in `exec'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:18:in `eval'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:32:in `call'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:57:in `compile'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/coffee.rb:46:in `evaluate'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:106:in `block in build_required_assets'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `build_required_assets'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:20:in `block in compile'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sprockets-2.1.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top
 (required)>'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top
 (required)>'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top     (required)>'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/Roseboom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125...]
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top
 (required)>'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top     (required)>'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/Roseboom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: looks like your `/home/Roseboom/gitControlled/ror/livescore/app/assets/javascripts/clubs.js.coffee` is not valid

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but I do not think that this is it, since they are autogenerated and a few weeks ago. I edited my question based on your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change execjs to therubyracer gem. I had so many problems with execjs before i switched to rubyracer. Now all works.

```
group :assets do

  gem 'sass'
  gem 'coffee-script'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'therubyracer'

end
```

Cheers!

Comment: You rock! And stackoverflow as well. After spending hours to solve the issue, getting the answer here took less time than it took me to pose the question properly :). As I understand, execjs is just a buggy gem.

Comment: if you are using 1.9.3 you will find more "buggy" gems ;/

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I used a wrong version of Ruby. Remember to double-check the Ruby version of your project